# Can't get JSON data from 000webhost server with AngularJS $http.get

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I am trying to get data from my server in a HTML file.

I tried [w3 schools code](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_mysql) but when I try to use my server link it prints nothing.

Here is the angular code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>     
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http
      .get("http://rabikhan.net23.net/Bitm_Student_Project/src/test.php")
      .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
  });
</script>
```

and the php code

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("mysql4.000webhost.com", "a1724083_rhk", "r7224191", "a1724083_tour2");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT CompanyName, City, Country FROM customers");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
  $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $rs["CompanyName"] . '",';
  $outp .= '"City":"'   . $rs["City"]        . '",';
  $outp .= '"Country":"'. $rs["Country"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

**Question**

How can I have `echo($outp);` print the desired information?

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` to see what the server is returning, if anything? What does the response look like?

Comment: never manually create your own json , it is very prone to errors. Use `json_encode()` instead. Add an error handler to `$http` for more details

Answer (score 0):

change your php to:

```html
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $conn = new mysqli("mysql4.000webhost.com", "a1724083_rhk", "r7224191", "a1724083_tour2");

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT CompanyName AS Name, City, Country FROM customers");

    // create an empty output array
    $output = array();
    while ($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // add record to output array
        $output.push($rs); 
    }

    $conn->close();

    // return output array as proper json
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

I also noticed that you have some analytics code in your php response pointing to http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php, make sure not to append it to your JSON responses